# Merging two observables of the same type results in "unknown" type

Tags: typescript, rxjs

I'm trying to create a function which returns an observable of an array + an optional additional element (if provided), both of type `Timeformat`

```
systemFormats: Timeformat[] = [
  new Timeformat('d/b/Y:T', "%d/%b/%Y:%T"),
  new Timeformat('Y-m-d T', "%Y-%m-%d %T"),
  new Timeformat('d.m.Y', "%d.%m.%Y"),
];

public getSystemFormats$(): Observable<Timeformat> {
  return from(this.systemFormats);
}


public getCandidates$(customFormat?: Timeformat) {    
   return merge(this.getSystemFormats$, from([customFormat]))
     .pipe(
      map(f => {    
        console.log(f.label);
      })          
    )
  }
```

However, `Observable.merge` seems to return an incorrect type, as I get the following error:

> Property 'label' does not exist on type 'unknown'

I tried different ways of casting the merge result into an `Observable<Timeformat>` but it doesn't help.

Comment: have you tried to infere the type? merge<TimeFormat>()

Comment: If you hover over `f`, what does it display?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the parameter, `customFormat?`

```
public getCandidates$(customFormat?: Timeformat) {    
   return merge(this.getSystemFormats$, from([customFormat]))
     .pipe(
      map(f => {    
        console.log(f.label);
      })          
    )
  }
```

By adding the question mark, the result is a customFormat or empty, which loses your typing.

Try this:

```
     .pipe(
       filter(Boolean),
       map(f: customFormat => {    
        console.log(f.label);
      })
```

Or if you don't really need it, remove the `?` from the parameter.